# how to configure datepicker using bootstrap3?

Tags: codeigniter, twitter-bootstrap, datepicker

I'm currently using bootstrap3 and Codeigniter latest verion and I have any problem with datepicker 
    **after I can't get datepicker with bootstrap3 I have try to use jquery datepicker as below code**

```
<link href="<?PHP echo base_url() ?>bootstrap-3/dist/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
<div class="my_wraper">
                <div class="col-xs-0 col-sm-1 placeholder">
                    <a class="btn btn-primary"
                        href="<?php echo base_url('invoice/add')?>">Add</a>
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-0 col-sm-10 placeholder">
                    <form action="" method="post">
                        <input class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" type="button" name="" value="Search" >
                        <input class="col-xs-3 form-control" id="inputSuccess4" type="text" name="" placeholder="name, in_id, amount, cus name, fiber no" /> 

                        <input class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" type="button" name="" value="Filter by Invoice type" >
                        <select class="col-xs-1 form-control">
                            <option class="testing" value="C15+">All</option>  
                            <option class="testing" value="C15+">Deposit</option>  
                            <option class="testing" value="C15+">Prepayment</option>  
                            <option class="testing" value="C15+">Monthly fee</option>  
                            <option class="testing" value="C15+">Installation fee</option>  
                        </select>
                         <input class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" type="button" name="" value="filter" >
                         <input class="col-xs-1 form-control" type="text"/> 
                        <span class="btn btn-sm">To</span>
                         <input class="datepicker col-xs-1 form-control" type="text"/> 
<input class="datepicker" type="text"/> 
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>


        <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.2/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
          <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
          <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.2/jquery-ui.js"></script> 

  <script type="text/javascript">
            // When the document is ready
            $(document).ready(function () {
                $('.datepicker').datepicker({
                    format: "dd/mm/yyyy"
                });  

            });
        </script>
```

---

Here is bootstrap datepicker library that I used to get datepicker for my above form but it still not working for me

```
<script src="js/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
        <script src="js/bootstrap-datepicker.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            // When the document is ready
            $(document).ready(function () {

                $('#example1').datepicker({
                    format: "dd/mm/yyyy"
                });  

            });
        </script>
```

How can I do or what i'm wrong with this structure

Comment: Check this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/anpsmn/574gg9g8/). The datepicker is working with your code. In the script, you have mentioned id `#example1` which doesn't exist in the HTML. You have to use the class `.datepicker` there.

Comment: Oh I corrent it already

Comment: Check firebug console or any other console of your browser. Did you get any errors?

Comment: <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
    <script src="<?PHP echo base_url().'bootstrap-3/dist/js/jquery1.11.js'?>"></script>
it is not show up when I used jquery1.11 and when i removed it to 1.10.2 it work so mean that jquery.1.11.... have not datepicker right?

Comment: I just want to know what did you get in console while you load your page? if any errors please mention it.

Comment: Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined jquery-ui.js:14(anonymous function) jquery-ui.js:14(anonymous function) jquery-ui.js:16
Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined 
I get this errors

Comment: Your jquery cdn //code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js not working try to replace it with local copy of jquery than it works.

Comment: <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo base_url('bootstrap-3/datepicker/css/jquery-ui.css')?>">
       <script src="<?php echo base_url('bootstrap-3/datepicker/js/jquery-1.10.2.js')?>"></script>
      <script src="<?php echo base_url('bootstrap-3/datepicker/js/ui.1.11.2.jquery-ui.js') ?>"></script>

it is work only with jquery-1.10.2.js and it doesn't work with jquery.1.11.js

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/64677/discussion-between-indrasinh-bihola-and-hengsopheak).